# Как сделать поиск по регулярным выражениям в Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

**Не ищет по регулярным выражениям в Elasticsearch**

- Индекс: items
- Поле: lot_description
- Регулярное выражение: Pan.sonic

Выполняю такой запрос в консоли:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/items/_search' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-d '{"query": 
    {"regexp": 
        {"lot_description": 
            {"value": "Pan.sonic"}}}}'
```

Результат:

```
{"took":8,"timed_out":false,"_shards":
    {"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0},
    "hits":
        {"total":{"value":0,"relation":"eq"},
    "max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

Ничего не находит. Но такие строчки точно есть

Comment: Мб потому что так надо `Pan.sonic` => `Pan.*sonic`? Иначе какой смысл в этой регулярке...

Comment: Для примера написал, разные регулярки пробовал. Даже просто слово пишешь, которое точно есть в поле и все равно не находит

Comment: А вам принципиально regexp? Можно ведь через wildcard сделать аля `"query" : { "bool": { "must": [{ "wildcard": { "lot_description": "Pan*sonic" } }] } }`

Comment: Почитал про wildcard, они могут только один или несколько символов заменять. У меня регулярки будут разные, поэтому не подойдет. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: `..."lot_description" : "Pan.*sonic"...` - так попробуйте

Comment: Результат тот же. Даже когда пишу слово полностью "Panasonic" он ничего не находит...Как будто сам запрос не правильно составил. Читал в официальной документации, все вроде по правилам. Но все равно нулевой результат

Comment: Нашел причину!
Регулярка срабатывает только в том случае, если в ней все буквы в нижнем регистре. В описании нигде такого не встречал